# Jenkins roll back to a previous release

Tags: jenkins

Can I set up Jenkins to roll back and deploy a previous release (inclusive of previous environment variable), on command?

In other words, releases (binaries?) being saved in source control.

Comment: Do you mean "replay" a build job?

Comment: I don't want it to build, as for us that means compiling and also pulling in (possibly different) environment variables from a cloud repository.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should split build and deployment in two seperate jobs, so you can trigger deployment manually when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to publish your versioned release artifacts to a repository (such as Nexus for Java).

Then you can instruct Jenkins to pull whatever previous version you want from that repository.

The "rollback" would simply be a deployment of a previous version.

This implies that you are able to completely archive and deploy from a static set of artifacts, including database or other dependencies.